# What's "alarm mesh"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Langdon had been standing inside the men's room refusing to run from a crime he didn't commit, when Sophie began eyeing the plate glass window and examine the ***alarm mesh*** running through it.  Then she peered downward into the street, as if measuring the drop.

This is from the book *The Da Vinci  Code*.  I don't know what "alarm mesh" is.  Can someone help me to understand it?

Comment: Presumably the glass has fine wires running through it connected to the building's alarm system, so breaking it would set off the alarm.

Comment: I wouldn't expect all that much technical accuracy in Dan Brown's books. This also is a passage from The Da Vinci Code (chapter 67): "The Range Rover was Java Black Pearl, four‑wheel drive, standard transmission, with high‑strength **polypropylene lamps**, rear light cluster fittings, and the steering wheel on the right" . You can google polypropylene lamps: here is a typical example which would be perfect for a Range Rover :-) https://www.archiproducts.com/en/products/movisi/polypropylene-pendant-lamp-fiocco_54876 Maybe his researcher had a bad day.